# Examples of languages that lost auxiliary verbs

Tags: historical-linguistics, etymology, grammar, linguistic-typology, morphemes

I've been looking around and haven't found any examples of languages that at one point in the past had auxiliary verbs but then later lost them. I know that both the Germanic and Romance languages have developed them but is there any precedent for languages then losing them again if so how does the new grammar end up looking?

Comment: You're looking for languages that completely and entirely lack them now, despite having them in the past? I can think of languages that lost some of their auxiliaries, but some remained or new ones arose.

Comment: Depending on your exact definition of _auxiliary_, there are arguably no languages in the world that do not have auxiliaries.

Comment: @Draconis English being one such example! Outside occasional dialectal retentions the auxiliaries cunnan "to know how to" and  þurfan "to need" have been lost (along with many other preterite-present verbs that were not typically used as auxiliaries)

Answer (score 3):

Russian is an classical example of such a language. In Russian, the present tense forms of the verb “to be” merged into one, *есть*, and the use of his single form as a copula practically stopped, thus resulting in Russian verbless sentences, like *Это кот. Кот чёрный.* “This is a cat. The cat is black.” which literally is “This cat. Cat black.” Moreover, the verb “to be” also stopped to be used as an auxiliary verb. Of the four Common Slavic past tenses which were aorist, imperfect, perfect, and pluperfect, Russian has kept only the perfect tense which used to be formed with a present tense form of the auxiliary verb “to be” plus the verb in a special participial form with the suffix `-l`. Like all the participles, this L-participle could be inflected for gender and number and it agreed in these categories with the subject:

```
Old Russian:  Язъ  ѥсмь         писалъ.
              Язъ  ѥс-мь        писа-л-ъ.
              I    be-​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​.1.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​  write-​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​-​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​.​​​​​​​​​​
              I have written.

              Язъ  ѥсмь          писала.
              Язъ  ѥс-мь         писа-л-а.
              I    be-​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​.1.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​   write-​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​-​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​.​​​​​​​​​​
              I have written.

              Мы   ѥсмъ          писали.
              Мы   ѥс-мъ         писа-л-и.
              We   be-​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​.1.​​​​​​​​​​   write-​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​-​​​​​​​​​​
              We have written.
```

Now when the auxiliary “to be” is not used anymore, Russian has a weird situation: in the present-future tense the verbs are conjugated for person and number, but in the past the verb forms do not have the distinction in persons, but are actually declined for gender and number, like adjectives and participles:

```
Modern Russian:  Я писала.
                 Я писа-л-а.
                 I write-​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​-​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​.​​​​​​​​​​
                 I wrote.

                 Я писал.
                 Я писа-л-∅.
                 I write-​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​-​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​.​​​​​​​​​​
                 I wrote.

                 Мы писали.
                 Мы писа-л-и.
                 We write-​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​-​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
                 We wrote.
```

Answer (score 2):

For a specific auxiliary there are some good and well-documented examples,

e.g.: Romance languages acquired a periphrastic future tense with the auxiliary "to have" and lost it again—the auxiliary was absorbed in the new synthetic future tense endings. French and other Romance languages recently acquired a new periphrastic future tense with the auxiliary *aller* "to go".

Latin had a synthetic future (based on the endings -bo, -bi-, -bu-) that is lost in modern Romance.